# NSInternalInconsistencyException when reloading collectionView although without explanation

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, batch-updates

I am encountering an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` when trying to reload my UICollectionView. The error message states:

> Invalid batch updates detected: the number of sections and/or items returned by the data source before and/or after performing the batch updates are inconsistent with the updates.

The exception only occurs when I build my app using Xcode. However, when I install the same exact code from TestFlight, everything works as expected.

I believe that the issue is related to passing a different data to the collection view than what was there before, even though it's supposed to be the same. The exception happens in the `updateCollection()` function shown below.

Code snippet:

```
@objc private func updateCollection() {
    let oldResults = viewModel.results
    self.viewModel.updateData { [weak self]  in
        if let newResults = self?.viewModel.results {
            let changes = diff(old: oldResults, new: newResults)
            self?.collectionView.reload(changes: changes, section: 0, updateData: {
                self?.viewModel.results = newResults
            }, completion: { isFinished in
                if isFinished {
                    self?.collectionView.reloadData()
                    self?.updateEmptyHomeView()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

```
func updateData(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    results.removeAll()
    let uid = self.id
    if let user = DataManager.getUser(id: uid) {
        self.results = user.getData()
        completion()
    } else {
        completion()
    }
}
```

This is the full error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid batch updates detected: the number of sections and/or items returned by the data source before and/or after performing the batch updates are inconsistent with the updates.
> Data source before updates = { 1 section with item counts: [8] }
> Data source after updates = { 1 section with item counts: [8] }

Can anyone help me identify what might be causing this inconsistency and why it only occurs when I build the app in Xcode?

Comment: I have solved the issue by downgrading the Xcode to 14.1 version and updating the support of IOS16.4. Some why this crashes in Xcode 14.3